# Is this good used harddisk or not?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

[image: Values pic 1]

[image]

[image]

Is this good used harddisk or not?

Comment: It says health and performance are at 100% It cannot get any better than that.

Comment: Good for what? See Moab's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Hard Disk Sentinel says this in your second image:

> The hard disk status is PERFECT. Problematic or weak sectors were not found and
> there are no spin up or data transfer error.

I think this text is clear - the disk is in excellent health.